Rotation invariant representation of strings
I came across the following simple programming question:
You need to create a boolean function that will return True if you get String A by shifting the alphabets in String B.
Example:
A = 'abid'
B = 'bida'
can_shift(A, B) == True

The proposed solution simply finds the possible rotations of B and compares them to A.
I am not a mathematician but I'm very interested in it. I want to create a function that produces a rotation-invariant string identifier and prove its correctness. Or prove that no such function exists. I thought of the following:
A: set of characters
Define a function f(x): AxAxA -> {0, 1}^n where n = |A|^3. It works similar to an indicator function. The input is a string of length 3, namely a triplet. The output is a vector of zeros, except at one dimension, where it is one. The dimension that corresponds to the specific triplet.
The function T(s) takes a string s and returns the set of all triplets in s. For example, if s="abid", then T(s) = {"abi", "bid", "ida", "dab"}.
The function id(s) sums f(t) over all t in T(s). If a string s2 is a rotation from s1, then id(s1)=id(s2), this is obvious. If id(s1) = id(s2), can we prove that s2 is a rotation from s1? Or give a counter-example?

If in your example of $T(s)$ you allow "dab", then I guess you consider the string as cyclic, so why not "ida"?

@CaptainLama yes you're right. i didnt notice. i edited it

Even if you look at the multiset of triples, rather than the set (so you count multiplicities), this is not true. There is an example where s1 = "aabbaaccaadd" for example...

One of the simplest approaches you can take is to find an ordering of possible rotations, and then pick the smallest thing by that ordering. For example, you could sort rotations alphabetically.

@IzaakvanDongen I didn't get the example. what would s2 be in that case?

s2 would have to be some permutation of s1. Can you think of a permutation of this string which "looks locally similar", but which is not a rotation?

@IzaakvanDongen oh yeah you're right. "aaccaabbaadd"
